# How can I orient a circle relative to the position of a 3D object?

Tags: opengl

How can I orient a circle that has a position to a 3D object? If I have a 3D object which is a hemisphere, I would like to let the circle be underneath that hemi-sphere and whenever the hemisphere moves, the circle move with the same angle and position, and underneath it.

In other words, I would like to attach a 2D circle to a hemisphere and parallel to it.

Comment: That's still not really clear...

Comment: @byte56, I have edited it.

Comment: Even post-edit I have no idea what you are asking about.

Comment: Your language is very imprecise. What do you mean by orientation? When you say circle, are you talking about a sphere, or some kind of 2d projection, or what? (EDIT) It was actually a little more clear before you deleted everything.

Comment: Can you draw a simple picture of what it would look like perhaps?

Comment: @TimHolt I added a picture.

I would like the the circle that is formed by the 5 points in the circle, to be parallel and perpendicular to the jellyfish.

Comment: I guess you want a smaller ring inside your jellyfish to follow the top hemisphere (the blue part) that you're animating. This smaller ring is where the tendrils of the jellyfish would attach?

Comment: yes. very correct.

Comment: First you need to have some kind of orientation for your object. That's a 3D vector. Then you need to "draw a circle" around that axis.. it shouldn't be difficult.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have an orientation defined for your object/entity. This is usually an unit vector in 3D, **v**=*(vx,vy,vz)*. If you have an [object oriented bounding box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_volume), then you can use that to determine where the "bottom" part of your object is. If not, just consider a "safety" distance/radius from the center of your object. Say this distance is *d*. Then one can simply find where the circle's center is by using the object's center, the **v** direction and the *d* distance:

```
 CircleCenter = ObjectCenter - d * v
```

**How to draw** the circle? It might seem like a difficult task. In 2D, that's trivial:
**circle(x,y,r) = (r*cos(u) +x, r*sin(u) + y)**, where *u between [0, 360] degs*.

In 3D you can draw it in the xOy plane, via its parametric equation:
**circle(0,0,0,r) = (r*cos(u), r*sin(u), 0)**

What to do next? Rotate the circle in such a way that its local Z(up) axis points in the same direction as the **v** vector. How? Find the rotation that aligns Z with **v**:

```
 w = cross((0,0,1), v)
 circle = RodriguesRotation(w, angle(v,(0,0,1)) * (r*cos(u), r*sin(u),0) + CircleCenter
```

The [RodriguesRotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula) is the general rotation matrix against a *w* axis by an angle *theta*.
In the picture below, the black arrow is the orientation, the red circle with red orientation arrows is what your circle should look like, and the crimson line is the *d* distance offset from the object's center.

[image]

Comment: I use cinder library and there is no support for the rodriguesRotation

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle It's not too difficult to code it though